# C: database for storing command history

Tags: c, data-structures, storage

I want to create a run dialog, i implemented interface and command run, but i'm stalled on following: i need some storage of strings which will be able to provide me slices beginning with specified string or all strings sorted by added date. I didn't find any solution :( I thought about sqlite, but it seems to be to much for such simple task. Plus such storage can be really big (i.e. atm i've got 5MB run history, ~7000 commands).

Any ideas?
Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not use a simple text file? Looks like it's certainly enough.

Comment: That's what bash does. Actually I think bash stores it in memory and writes the .bash_history file when you exit. Also you probably want to get rid of entries older than a certain amount, either by time or by number of lines of command history.

Answer (score 0):

sqlite is good option and it it similar to using a text file. Also you can remove the history based on dates easily in sqlite then in simple text file.
Also searching in sqlite will be much easier then in text file and amount of code to be written will be much less in case of sqlite.